java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object) on a null object referenceat atttt
I am getting this error at runtime.
enter image description here
ERROR:
FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Process: com.example.simplesocialmediaapp, PID: 5101
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
at com.example.simplesocialmediaapp.Fragments.CircleFragment$1.onDataChange(CircleFragment.java:66)
at com.google.firebase.database.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(ValueEventRegistration.java:75)
at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.DataEvent.fire(DataEvent.java:63)
at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(EventRaiser.java:55)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7924)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)


This is the code after I finished it and got an error
public class CircleFragment extends Fragment{

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    List<CircleModel>circlModelList;
    CircleAdapter mAdapter;
    FirebaseUser firebaseUser;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_circle, container, false);
        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview_users);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));

        displayusers();

        return view;
    }


    private void displayusers() {
        circlModelList = new ArrayList<>();

        DatabaseReference reference  = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");
        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                circlModelList.clear();

                for (DataSnapshot ds: snapshot.getChildren()) {

                    CircleModel circleModel = ds.getValue(CircleModel.class);

                    firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

                    if (!circleModel.getId().equals(firebaseUser.getUid())) {


                        circlModelList.add(circleModel);

                    }


                    mAdapter  = new CircleAdapter(getContext(), circlModelList);
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);








                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
    }
}


Looks like circleModel.getId() is returning null, and you can't call a method on a null reference.  You're going to have to do some debugging to figure out why this is - we can't do this for you, nor can we see your data.
